# two javascript arrays and display result with count

Tags: javascript

Hi I have two javascripts arrays and I want to display result in below way (specified in desired result table):

```
array1 = ( '2013/01/02','2013/01/03','2013/01/02','2013/01/02' );
array2 = ( 'a' ,'b', 'c', 'a' );
```

I need result in below format but in HTML page:

```
       2013/01/02   2013/01/03  
a          2            0  
b          0            1  
c          1            0
```

hints: array1 1st value link with array2 1st value, array1 2nd value link with array2 2nd value ... 
How many 2013/01/02 and a ? if we compare two arrays ? count is 2 but should display in matrix

Comment: Your seconds array isn't valid, or is that a typo, and as mentioned by @tymeJV: what? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: array1 = ( '2013/01/02','2013/01/03','2013/01/02','2013/01/02' );
array2 = ( 'a' ,'b', 'c', 'a' );

 and want output in below way 

        2013/01/02   2013/01/03
a          2  0 <BR>
b          0            1 <BR>
c          1            0 <BR> edited my question in proper format by megawac. can someone help give simple code if possible.

Comment: Hi thanks for get back to me. Basically I want to display specified format table in HTML . But that table should created based on two arrays. Example array1 first value is linked with array2 1st value, array1 2nd value linked to array2 2nd value ... I hope

Comment: I have updated my question. Please look and let me know if you are still unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count unique values use:

```
array1 = [ '2013/01/02','2013/01/03','2013/01/02','2013/01/02' ];
array2 = [ 'a' ,'b', 'c', 'a' ];

var counts = {};
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (!counts[array1[i]])
        counts[array1[i]] = {};
    if (counts[array1[i]][array2[i]])
        counts[array1[i]][array2[i]] += 1;
    else
        counts[array1[i]][array2[i]] = 1;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aM6X2/10/).

Using two `foreach` loops you get your desired table ([JQuery.each DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aM6X2/11/)).

Comment: but this code help me to get count if I have only one array. If i have two arrays then how can i get result as specified in my question. could you please help me.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. It works in that way what I was expecting. But I am getting repeated date if I am using this code:

array1 = [ '2013/01/02','2013/01/03','2013/01/02','2013/01/02' ];
array2 = [ 'a' ,'b', 'c', 'a' ];
var tt = "";
var ttt = "";
var tttt = "";

var counts = {};
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (!counts[array1[i]])
        counts[array1[i]] = {};
    if (counts[array1[i]][array2[i]]) {

Comment: counts[array1[i]][array2[i]] += 1;
  // ttt += array1[i];
  // tttt += array2[i];
  tt += counts[array1[i]][array2[i]];
    } else {
        counts[array1[i]][array2[i]] = 1;
  tt += counts[array1[i]][array2[i]];
  ttt += array1[i];
  tttt += array2[i];
  }
}

document.write (tt+"-->"+ttt+"--->"+tttt);

Result:
1112-->2013/01/02,2013/01/03,2013/01/02--->abc  where I want following result:
1112-->2013/01/02,2013/01/03--->abc